# How to click on multiple links(onclick events) and extract content and append them to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, onclick, dom-manipulation

consider few links in the selector of `.bdView > .row > div a[onclick]` , when clicked on each link relevant content will be loaded on both #amendinfo0 , #amendinfo1 div tags on a onclick event. How do i extract the content loading on #amendinfo0 , #amendinfo1 div tags and append them in to a new div

example for a tag:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="amendinfoBtn('art1', 'art')">Article 1</a>
```

Below is what i tried:

```
var links = $('.bdView >.row > div a[onclick]');

var combinedContentDiv = $('<div>');

links.each(function() {
  var onclickAttr = $(this).attr('onclick');
  
  var content = onclickAttr.match(/'#amendinfo\d+'/g).map(function(selector) {
    return $(selector).html();
  }).join('');
  combinedContentDiv.append(content);
});

$('body').append(combinedContentDiv);
```

Comment: You want to extract the articles that are loaded from elsewhere when `amendinfoBtn('art1', 'art')` is clicked? Or just want to extract the string `art1` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to extract the content of articles which are loading from elsewhere(article content are loading on #amendinfo0 , #amendinfo1 div tags)  when the links are clicked

Comment: @vinoojayakody If the content is loaded _after the user clicks the `<a>` tag_, you cannot eagerly copy it from the current document because _it is not inside the current document before the user clicks_ - you need to know the URL(s), then replace the current `onclick` event handler with one that you control which loads the new content(s) and after loading places the article(s) into the DOM.

Comment: You need to show the `amendinfoBtn` function